# Doesn't setTextView

Tags: java, android, textview

My android app doesn't display any values even though it has its own right ids. Why doesn't it work? Thanks

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
int[] marks = {1, 2, 4, 5};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    for (int i = marks.length; i == 0; i--) {
        int total = 0;
        total = total + marks[i];
        float markAvereage = (float) total / marks.length;
        setMarkText(i, markAvereage);
    }
}
private void setMarkText(int i, float markAvereage) {
    String textViewID = "mark" + i;
    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(textViewID, "id", getPackageName());
    TextView markTv = ((TextView) findViewById(resID));
    markTv.setText("Ø "+ (int) markAvereage);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  int[] marks = {1, 2, 4, 5};
  LinearLayout mLinearLayout;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    setContentView(mLinearLayout);
    mLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    for (int i = 0; i <= marks.length; i++) {
        float markAverage = (float) i / marks.length;
        setMarkText(markAverage);

    }
}

  private void setMarkText(float markAverage) {
      TextView markTv = new TextView(this);
      markTv.setText(String.valueOf(markAverage));
      mLinearLayout.addView(markTv);
  }
}
```

Comment: But even this code you pasted doesn't work because you have to put 3 parameters into method setMarkText and you put there just 2

Comment: The resID is declared outside the loop so it can't reach inside the for loop

Comment: This worked for me, take a look and let me know if it does for you. I'll update the original answer explaining the differences, after you let me know it works.

Comment: It works but it adds its own views and doesnt fill in the layouted ones